# Does a pointer get the same memory address after deleting it and allocating new memory again in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-c++, memory-management, memory-address

> Here's the thing I wanted to clarify. I have another function to display links. After calling that display function I got a garbage value on my console.
>   But when I commented "delete temp" statement it worked fine, I got results as expected. Please do help. Thanks.

```
void MyLinkedList::insertFirst(double data){
    MyLink *temp = new MyLink(data);
    temp->next = first;
    first = temp;
    delete temp;
}
```

Comment: `delete temp;` disposes of the memory previously allocated with `new`, so once the function returns `first` will be pointing to unallocated memory. Any attempt to access data via the `first` pointer results in UB (undefined behavior).

Comment: @dxiv Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete operator is not for deleting the pointer itself but to delete the memory pointed by it.

```
 MyLink *temp = new MyLink(data); //allocate space for a MyLink dataType
 first=tmp; //temp still points to the allocated space
 delete temp; //deallocate the memory space pointed by temp which is the same memory space pointed by first.
```